# Is it possible to only rebuild/reload the client code in sapper when a svelte component is modified

Tags: svelte, rollup, sapper

We have a fairly large [project](https://www.harnessautomation.com/gem) built in sapper/svelte. In dev when a file changes it recompiles both the client and server even though I have only modified a single svelte component.

This was fine when the project was small but now changes take around 30 seconds for each reload and a bunch of redundant processes are executed on server startup (data layer initialization, connection to many IoT devices, etc). It is proving to be a bit of a bottleneck for us as the project has grown.

Is it possible to have rollup only rebuild and reload the client code when a svelte component has changed and leave the server as-is in a running state?

Comment: Use two separate rollup instances, the rollup instance that builds client side code can run in watch mode, but server side one must not be watching.

Comment: I still want the server to rebuild if a server file is modified. It just happens much less frequently than the client code. I wonder if there is a hook to get the context of what changed and kick off a specific rollup instance.

Comment: Not that I know of. But having two instances both running in watch mode will just give you the desired effect.

Comment: But you need to make sure what part to watch on server side then. Honestly I never use sapper, not sure if this is possible. I guess it’s not, cus server code is superset of client code.